# What are offerings to shivalinga and what are fruits of it?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, shiva-lingam

What are offerings to `shivalinga` and what are fruits of it? It is said that if we offer water of river **Ganga**, we attain `Moksha` after death, similarly milk is offered for long life. But this information is not authentic as I read on websites. Also I could not find similar questions on stack exchange site.

Please provide authentic information of what fruit is obtained by specific offering. I would love to hear the related source or scripture too, for instance Shiva or Linga Purana.

Comment: Wow, This post is now on the HNQ! Congrats :) Just edit your post to remove the last line as Thanks is not required in Stack Exchange posts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The details of how to perform Shiva Linga Archana(including the details of mantras to be used etc) are briefed in the [Lingaarchana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/lingapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=6) chapter of LingaPurana:

> As Rishis asked Lomaharshana Maharshi as to the Procedure of
>   Lingaarchana or Worship the Shiva Linga, the Maharshi stated that once
>   Devi Parvati also inquired of  the same and Shiva Himself revealed the
>   Procedure:

And, we gather the following information regarding what are the objects/items that should be offered to a Shiva Linga:

> Maharshi Lomavarshana now described the actual Procedure of
>   Rudraabhisheka as follows......Then Shiva is seated at the Center
>   firmly; He  would be seated as Sadyojata Shiva with the Mantra of
>   Vaamaa Deva; Rudra Gayatri is seated with Aghora Mantra; and Ishana is
>   seated by reciting
>
> Ishaanassarva Vidyaanaam Ishwarassarva Bhutaanaam
>
> Brahmaadipatih Brahmanoddhi Patih Brahma Shivomey astu Sadaa Shivom/
>
> Then the devotee should worship Shiva Linga with
>   Paadya-Arghya-Achamanaas; perform Snaana with **Gandha-Chandana**;
>   implement formal Snaana with **Pancha-Gavya** or of Cow’s Five Bye
>   Products; carry out Abhishka with **Ghee, Honey, Sugar, Pavitra Jala**
>   along Pranava Naada. There after, clean up the residues of the
>   Abhisheka material on the Linga with a clean cloth and decorate the
>   Linga with flower garlands comprising fresh flowers like **Jaati,
>   Champaka, Kapura, Kannera, Chameli, and Kadamba**

So,for abhisekha apart from **water**(including water from holy rivers like Ganges), the **Pancha Gavyas** & the **Panchamritas** are required alongwith **sandal paste**.

Further info gathered from [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/lingapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=14) chapter of the same Purana:

> In all the months, the puja must be performed by **lotus either in the
>   actual form preferably or by way of gold or silver or copper or any
>   other forms.** Puja by **Bilva Patra (Shri Patra)** again **in actual form or
>   of replicas would be a ‘must’**. Devi Lakshmi is stated to reside in bel
>   patras, while Neel Kamal is the resident of Ambika, Shanmukha stays in
>   Utpala Pushpa and **Maha Deva is fond of Padma**. Dhupa or smoke made of
>   **‘Guggula’ and Deepa are integral parts of the Puja as they are the
>   demolishers of all kinds of sins.**

For naivedya Lord Shiva likes **Anna(rice)** as stated below:

> **As for Naivedya, ‘Shuddhhaanna’ would satisfy Maha Deva;** in fact,
>   ‘Anna Daana’ is one significant charity to the needy that Shiva is
>   always desirous of on any day, especially on Puranamasi.

Ingredients for Shiva Abhisheka on special months are also given in the same chapter like:

> Kartika Month: The entire month is of significance and daily
>   Shivaarchana-Abhisheka with Sacred water, Milk, Coconut water, Curd,
>   Ghee, Chandana, and Bhasma with Maha Nyasa Purvaka, Maha Rudra Purvaka
>   Snaanaas to Shiva Linga,

Relative importance of offering/bathing Lingam with water,milk,ghee etc , taken from [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/lingapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=13) chapter of the Linga Purana, are as follows:

> Mere ‘darshana’ of such Sacred Tirthas is of considerable value, but
>   ‘sparshana’ or touch and fondling of a Shiva Linga is hundred times
>   better;  **Abhisheka of Shiva Lingas with water is hundred times better;
>   Abhisheka with milk is thousand times better; far better is the
>   Abhisheka with curds; with Madhu or honey it is regarded as better
>   still and  even better would be the Abhisheka by ghee.**

I am unable to find,though, the exact rewards for offering each of the above items to Shiva Lingam.Although I think that they are present in some Scriptures(telling you that from my memory). Will be on look out for those.

**EDIT**-In general by the worship of Shiva Linga one gets everything starting from worldly benefits to Moksha,but I'm yet found the exact fruits of offering specific objects.

From the  [Shiva Linga Pratishta Vidhi and Mahatmya](http://%20Shiva%20Linga%20Pratishta%20Vidhi%20and%20Mahatmya) chapter of Linga Purana:

> Linga Devi Uma Devi Lingam Saakshaanmaheswarah /
>
> Tayoh sapujanaa Deva Devascha Pujitou,
>
> Pratishthayaa cha Devesho Devyaa saardham prtishthitah/
>
> Muley Brahmaa vasati Bhagavan Madhya bhaagey cha
>
> Vishnuh Sarveshaanah Pashupati rajo Rudramurthirvarenyah,
>
> Tasmaalingam Gurutatataram Pujatsthaapayedhaa
>
> yasmaad pujyo Ganapatirasau Deva Mukhyaih samastaih/
>
> Gandhaih snugdhupa deepaih snapanahuta balistotrra
>
> mantropahaaraih nityam  yebhyarchayaanti tridasha vastunam Linga
>   murtey Mahesham/
>
> Tasmaat Bhaktopchaarena Staapayet Parameshwaram,
>
> Pujayeccha visheshena Lingam Sarvaartha siddhayai/

Meaning-

> The Vedi of the Shiva Linga is Uma Devi herself and the Linga is
>   Maheswara himself; thus the Linga ought to be installed along with the
>   Vedi. The Shiva Linga’s bottom is signified as Brahma and the middle
>   part is signified as Vishnu and the top portion is Maheswara himself.
>   This is why the high significance of the Rudra Swarupa Pashupati. By
>   installing the Linga thus, regular pujas should be performed most
>   sincerely along with Gandha, Dhupa, Deepa, Snaana, Havana, Bali,
>   Stotra, Mantra and Upahaara. **Nitya Puja is a must and this would
>   ensure freedom from ‘Punarjanma’ or rebirth, Shiva Loka Prapti and
>   worship-worthiness of Deva-Gandharva-Siddha and Shiva ganaas.**

Comment: No problem bro.  :) @ABcDexter

Comment: The way this is written, it sound like the lingam proper is being worshiped, rather than God being worshiped through the lingam. Is that really so?

Comment: Worshipping the Linga and worshipping Lord Shiva is not different. Linga already had got life force of God infused in it through appropriate rituals. @RubelliteYakṣī

Comment: @Rickross I find that unconvincing. My understanding was that effigies, including linga & yoni, are foci and not incarnations or versions of the deity proper. I would love a better understanding. I can be reached in chat.

Comment: Those are not incarnations coz they don't have Prana or life force from the start. Whether it's an image/idol or a Yantra or a Lingam, we worship it only after invoking the life force of the deity within that. Those objects are called Adharas of Puja and there are many such Adharas. The elaborate process of invoking life into lifeless objects like idols is called Pranapratishta. It involves Mantras and other rituals. Search for the term on Google. @RubelliteYakṣī

Comment: Anna should be cooked rice or uncooked rice grains?

Comment: @TigerShroff You mean for Naivedyam? Only cooked.. If asking for bathing then both are offered I replied under ur Q.

Comment: What is naivedyam?

Comment: Naivedyam means the food offering which he actually will eat.. Do you know about a Shodasha Upachara Puja? @TigerShroff

Comment: If you want to know about Pancha (5) Upacharas, Shodasha (16) Upacharas in a Puja then u can read the following answer. Naivedya is a Pancha Upachara as well as a Shodasha Upachara. @TigerShroff https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18404/what-is-offered-during-arati-and-what-they-represent/18408#18408