# Scriptural basis for the Shodashopchar Puja?

Tags: scripture, rituals, worship, agamas

What is the earliest reference to *Shodashopchar Puja* in scriptures?

Which scriptures gives the exact details of its procedure?

Comment: See this answer (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18408/4732) and this (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20292/4732)

Comment: @Rickross Thanks a lot, it further clarifies my doubt!

Comment: Had a small follow-up question. Is this the right place to ask? (new here)

Comment: You can ask in comments or else you can a post a Q too @Ravi

Comment: Oh fine, I frame an elaborate Q itself. Thanks again.

Comment: Any Puja has 3 parts in general .( Poorvanga , Pradhana ,Uttaranga.). Shodachopachara usually follows pooja sankalpa, (pranaprathishta)that occurs in the Pradana part. Despite it adhers to a common template , it's passages are customized according to the deity/pooja.In practice one simply follows a Puja vidhi / Puja vidhan book designed by subject experts from sources, (containg sufficient info).Not sure if any one would really pick a particular Pooja vidhi from a Purana and follow.

Comment: @Athrey Hmm...so are these Puja Vidhi Books developed by combining relevant knowledge from multiple Puranas/Agamas?

Answer (score 4):

The whole concept is sixteen upacharas is explained in [Skanda Purana.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502218.html)

Indra worshipped Devi Lakshmi with these 16 upacharas.

> Indra worshipped devotedly with sixteen upacāras (articles offered). Every upacāra (article) was offered with the repetition of mantra. All the things were very excellent, right and commendable. “O Mahā Lakṣmī!

> **Devi Bhagwatam (9:42)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what does "earliest references" mean. Because of the cyclic nature of time in Hinduism theology (cf. Srimada Bhagvad [Geeta 2.13](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2/verse/12)) every text in of Hinduism has an eternal antiquity.

References to *shodashopachara puja* are found in numerous texts like Puranas and tantras, etc.

One such reference is found in the Shiva Purana.

Shiva Purana mentions about the *shodashopachara* (षोडशोपचार) form of worship.

[Shiva Purana Verse 1.7.25-29](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225552.html)

> अथवा चरलिंगं तु **षोडशैरुपचारकैः** ॥ २५ ॥
> पूजयेच्च यथान्यायं
> क्रमाच्छिवपदप्रदम् । आवाहनं चासनं च अर्घ्यं पाद्यं तथैव च ॥ २६
> ॥
> तदंगाचमनं चैव स्नानमभ्यंगपूर्वकम् । वस्त्रं गंधं तथा पुष्पं धूपं
> दीपं निवेदनम् ॥ २७ ॥
> नीराजनं च तांबूलं नमस्कारो विसर्जनम् ।
> अथवाऽर्घ्यादिकं कृत्वा नैवेद्यां तं यथाविधि ॥ २८ ॥
> अथाभिषेकं
> नैवेद्यं नमस्कारं च तर्पणम् । यथाशक्ति सदाकुर्यात्क्रमाच्छिवपदप्रदम् ॥
> २९ ॥
>
> > The sixteen types of service are:—invocation (Āvāhana);
> > offering the seat (Āsana); water offering (Arghya); washing of the
> > feet (Pādya); water for rinsing the mouth as a mystical rite
> > (Ācamana); oil bath (Abhyaṅga snāna); offering of cloth (Vastra);
> > Scents (Gandha); flowers (Puṣpa); incense (Dhūpa); lamps (Dīpa); food
> > offering (Nivedana); waving of lights (Nīrājana); betel leaves
> > (Tāmbūla); obeisance (Namaskāra); and mystical discharge and
> > conclusion (Visarjana)
>
> English Translation by J.L. Shastri.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Also, are you aware of its reference in any Vaishnava Purana / Agama ?

Comment: Well, if you consider the text - Hari Bhakti Vilasa, as a scripture, @Ravitej  then it does mention the Ṣoḍaśopacārapuja in Chapter 11 (Ekadash Vilasa), Verses 124-125. It further gives information on 64 forms of upacāras. You can refer the Sanskrit+Hindi Translation from [archive's website here](https://archive.org/details/hbv_vol2/page/n25/mode/1up?view=theater)

Comment: Great! Thanks again.

Comment: Yup. Upvoted already. Regarding accepting, thought it would disincentivize anyone pouring in more references.

Comment: Yeah, that was useful for sure :) Still figuring out how this platform works .

Comment: Pasting some links for you here @Ravitej . Hope this will help. :))  Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Kindly also visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions).

Comment: Whoa! Thanks a ton!!