# Honey on Shivling

Tags: worship, shiva-lingam, puja

What are the benefits of putting honey on Shivling as per scripture?

Comment: In Kali yuga everything is said to be impure. Do we have any option? If it is feasible to get natural honey, that's better, otherwise  just pray to Lord Siva and do it with devotion.

Comment: Ram see the following answer .. it says bathing Shiva Lingam with honey is next best to bathing it with Ghee, which is the most beneficial: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15930/what-are-offerings-to-shivalinga-and-what-are-fruits-of-it/15931#15931.. regarding use of honey that we get today, what can be done? we have to use those only.

Comment: @Rickross ok thanks. The benefits of each ingredients is not mentioned. Can you find those? I will edit my question accordingly.