# Different methods of doing Śivaliṅga Abhiṣekam?

Tags: shiva, puranas, astrology, shiva-lingam

What are different kinds and methods of *Śivaliṅga Abhiṣekam*? Several priests and *jyotiṣika* (astrologers) recommend doing *abhiṣekam* with water (*जल* ), milk (*दुग्ध* ), ***bhasman (भस्मन्)***, ***sugarcane juice (इक्षुरस)***, ***attar (इत्र)***, honey, curd, etc.. sometimes all together in tandem and sometimes alone, depending upon the reasons for doing the abhiṣekam.

For example - One of them said, do a *Rudra Abhiṣekam*, with the sugarcane juice for mitigating problems related to sudden accidents and deaths.

---

**Questions:-**

1. Where are these different rituals found in *puranic* or astrology based scriptures? What are the associated benefits ( as per relevant scriptures) for Abhiṣekam done with different liquids and/or offerings?
2. Are any particular kind of liquids forbidden to be used for Abhiṣekam (like *Kewra Water - केवड़ा जल* **?**) , just like certain flowers are forbidden?
3. Are there any specific stories which might relate why only these certain products are more favoured for the Abhiṣekam.

For example :-

- Story of Ketakí being cursed and thus not used.
- the story of *[bilwa patra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/873/what-is-the-significance-of-bel-leaves-in-shiva-worship/9716#9716)*, etc..

---

**Extremely Related Questions:**

1. [What is the significance of pouring milk on the Shivling?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/425/what-is-the-significance-of-pouring-milk-on-the-shivling/17187#17187)
2. [Honey on Shivling](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29707/honey-on-shivling)
3. [What are offerings to shivalinga and what are fruits of it?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15930/what-are-offerings-to-shivalinga-and-what-are-fruits-of-it/15931#15931)

Comment: https://www.dlshq.org/download/lordsiva.pdf

Comment: @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru , thanks for this pdf!

Comment: Your most welcome !